# Why TrimStart is working only when i assign the text again back th the variable?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
scrollerList = new List<string>(TextExtractor.newTextWithoutLinks);
scrollerText = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, scrollerList);
combindedString = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, newText);
scroller1.TextToScroll = scrollerText;
richTextBox1.Text = combindedString;
richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.TrimStart();
richTextBox1.Refresh();
```

This is a working line:

```
richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.TrimStart();
```

But if i'm doing:

```
richTextBox1.Text.TrimStart();
```

It's not working i mean dosen't make any changes.

Not that i'm getting any exceptions but a bit strange i need to assign twice to the richTextBox1 the text to delete the empty line at the top of the richTextBox1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string` is immutable - what you're seeing is expected behaviour.  Operations like `TrimStart()` will create a new `string`, which is returned when calling that method.

Why not do it in one go?

```
richTextBox1.Text = combindedString.TrimStart();
```

Answer (score 1):

`TrimStart()` returns a new string with the values trimmed. It does not modify the original string:

From [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> This method does not modify the value of the current instance.
>   Instead, it returns a new string in which all leading white space
>   characters found in the current instance are removed.

Answer (score 0):

It generates a new string, which has nothing to do with the old one. You have to replace the existing one with the new one!
So this is right:

```
richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.TrimStart();
```